# How to detect when a user is adding or removing a program in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My WPF app is like a MacBook dock which displays apps. I want to update the applications list within my app whenever the user installs or uninstalls a program.

**What would be a good way to capture that add/remove program event?**

As most people flagged for too broad I'm going to elaborate further:

1. I haven't tried anything yet. The only thing I'm thinking of is rescanning the registry every now and then to see if the program list has changed. This will work for sure, however, that's my backup option for now and I'm looking for a better solution.
2. By installed app I mean an application which has a registry key associated with it in either of these locations and therefore it shows up in the add/remove programs window.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

3. By uninstalled app I mean - a program you uninstalled from the add/remove program window.

Comment: installed apps are stored in a registry key, however you will need to hook the registry api,poll the registry, or potentially use the RegistryState Class

Comment: Your goal is not literally possible, because there is no standard for what constitutes "install" or "uninstall". Some programs can be run from a thumb drive. Are they installed when the thumb drive is inserted? Uninstalled when it's removed? Other programs install themselves to the hard drive, but in a non-standard way that is not visible to normal OS mechanisms. These are true for all mainstreams operations systems. Your question is too broad, as it's insufficiently constrained, and you haven't shown what you've tried so far, nor why that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Most apps like the one you're making require the user to manually add programs. Like Peter said, automatically detecting installed apps is a difficult problem to solve in Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it. When you add or remove a program(install/uninstall) Windows writes events in the Event Log(Event Viewer) under WindowsLogs/Application. You can listen to when a new log entry is added using EventLog.EntryWritten

```
EventLog eLog = new EventLog();
eLog.Log = "Application"; //MsiInstaller events are written in Application
eLog.EntryWritten += Log_NewInstallUninstallOccured; //Add the event and remove it when you want to stop listening
eLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // Enable event raising

private void Log_NewInstallUninstallOccured(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Entry.Source == "MsiInstaller") //MsiInstaller is the source responsible for installation related events
            {
                if(e.Entry.Message.Contains("Installation completed successfully."))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Installation Occured");
                }
                else if (e.Entry.Message.Contains("Removal completed successfully."))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Removal Occured");
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Other Installation Event Occured");
                }
            }
        }
```

Sources:

[How to tell which user installed or uninstalled an app in Windows](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-tell-which-user-installed-or-removed-an-app-in-windows/)

[EventLog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=netframework-4.8)

[EventLog.EntryWritten Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten?view=netframework-4.8)